# UAC Showing Limited User Account ["More Choices"]

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac, group-policy

It seems Windows 10 has in some way altered UAC behavior.

Previously only Administrator accounts would be enumerated in the UAC prompt, now however it is showing the current logged in standard user.

Even with "Enumerate Administrator Accounts on Elevation" disabled within group policy the current user is listed.

In order to provide administrator credentials I have to click "More Choices" and then "Use a Different Account".

This behavior is incredibly frustrating as I can no longer elevate without clicking multiple different things when before it was as simple as typing the necessary credentials as soon as the window opened.

Is there a solution to this? I'd really like the Windows 7 style, non-enumerated, dialog without this "More Choices" nuisance.

**Additional Info as requested:**

What I see when UAC opens:
[image: What I see when UAC opens]

What I expect UAC to do:
[image: What I expect UAC to do]

Note that I had to expand More Details in the second picture, normally (prior to whatever build changed it) that is collapsed and both username and password are required. Basic isn't even an admin so I'm uncertain how it shows in the system.

Windows 10 Enterprise Build 1607 (OS Build 14393.351)

Comment: Could you add pictures of your UAC dialog? What build of Win10 do you have?

Comment: @ge0rdi I added the relevant photos above, had to remove the reddit link as because of my low reputation (I didn't realize rep wasn't shared with StackOverflow) I cannot add more than 2 links.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation` disabled in local group policy editor? Also isn't `Basic` user member of `Administrator` group?

Comment: @ge0rdi I am certain that the policy is disabled.

[photo of the group policy](https://imgur.com/a/GrQgp)

The command "net user Basic" lists the following groups:

**Local Group Memberships**       Network Configuration, Users
**Global Group memberships**     None

Comment: It seems it is somehow related to `Network Configuration Operators` group. I can replicate the issue by adding my limited account to that group. Try to remove user `Basic` from the group.

Comment: @ge0rdi That seems to be the fix, is there a way to prevent enumeration of all groups in UAC?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know about a way to turn it off :(

Comment: also applies to Server 2016.  Sometimes it assumes my "naive" user, other times it goes straight-to-blank prompt.  Frustratingly inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you described is present if you have a user that is member of some of following groups

- `Backup Operators`
- `Cryptographic Operators`
- `Network Configuration Operators`
- `Power Users`

and `Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation` option is disabled in local group policy (otherwise one of `Administrators` is shown).

It may be a bug in Windows 10 1607, or it may be somehow intentional change. I cannot say that for sure.

The solution for your problem is to remove user from mentioned groups (you can always perform actions allowed to those groups by providing administrator credentials).