# How to extend default choices in User Account Control Pop Up

Tags: windows-10, security, user-accounts, popups

When I want to run an application as Administrator I have to use a different user.

The thing is that this case is repetitive and it is annoying to enter username and password each time.

The pop up that is showing gives me the current user as choices, can I also add another user to the default choices so when I need to use it I would only type the password?

[image: User Account Control Popup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot edit the list of options offered in the UAC dialog.

Two workarounds may be useful in this case:

1. You can Shift+right-click the application you're starting and choose **Run as different user** from the menu. This will prompt you for the credentials you wish to use.
2. Create a batch script that uses the `RUNAS` command to specify the account to use when launching the program. For example:

   ```
   Runas /user:domain\Alice "myapp.exe"
   ```

#### More Information

- [Runas command syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771525(v=ws.10))

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing `net localgroup Administrators User /add` into a command prompt with admin rights. Replace *User* with the user you would like to add to the UAC list.

Comment: Did not work,System error 1378 has occurred.
The specified account name is already a member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the `Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation` group policy setting is enabled, as follows:

1. Launch *Local Group Policy Editor* (Enter `gpedit.msc` into Windows search).
2. IN the *Local Computer Policy* tree navigate to `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `Credential User Interface`.
3. Open the setting `Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation` and set it to *Enabled*.

See also: [UAC Showing Limited User Account ["More Choices"]](https://superuser.com/questions/1141111/uac-showing-limited-user-account-more-choices)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround: I set my admin account logon with a different fingerprint. At the UAC screen I just place my "admin" finger on the reader and that works.
(Win 10 22H2, work PC in AD domain)