# Force UAC to prompt for user name and password

Tags: administrator, uac

Is there a way I can force UAC to pop up ***with no user assigned***, so that I can enter my Admin account and password?

#### Why

I have a standard account and an Admin account. Recently there was a change and now when I try to run something **as admin the UAC pops up with my standard name and I have to click <kbd>`More Choices`</kbd> and <kbd>`Use a different account`</kbd> every time**.

Comment: IIRC the dialog defaults to this if you do not have admin rights. Your "normal" account may now have admin rights.

Comment: check out the secpol.msc tweak here to disable "Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation" and see if that works. it should stop listing users for you to choose from, so you will have to type in the username on each elevation. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee1780a9-de0e-4b26-b352-351f2c58facb/remove-user-from-uac-list?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: What version of windows, and is the PC part of a domain? The default is no username in the auto-fill. Even when 'enumerate admins' is enabled, only actual admin accounts show up. If the normal user was an admin, the prompt is just yes/no, and not for a user

Comment: Running Windows 10 20h2, on a domain, my standard account definitely does not have admin rights, I have to have a work station admin account and a server admin account for different tasks.

Comment: @ClifB This looks like the same thing you're experiencing - is your normal user in some local groups? https://superuser.com/a/1144109/673426 . There should be a difference between that credential prompt you're getting and the normal elevation prompt based on your UAC settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works